# многомерный массив из php в json

Tags: php, json, json-encode

Есть массив который генерируется в php:

Сам код:

```
    $arr = [];
    $i = 0;
    while($arResult = $rsResult->GetNext())
    {
    
      $arr['categories'][$i]['id'] = $arResult['ID'];
      $arr['categories'][$i]['parentId'] = '';
      $arr['categories'][$i]['name'] = $arResult['NAME'];
      $arr['categories'][$i]['sortOrder'] = $arResult['SORT'];
      $arr['categories'][$i]['images']['hash'] = '';
      $arr['categories'][$i]['images']['url'] = CFile::GetPath($arResult['PICTURE']);
    
      $i++;
    
    };

echo json_encode($arr);
```

`print_r($arr)` - выводит:

```
Array
(
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 165
                    [parentId] => 
                    [name] => Овощи, фрукты, ягоды
                    [sortOrder] => 2
                    [images] => Array
                        (
                            [hash] => 
                            [url] => /upload/iblock/e76/ovoshchi_frukty.png
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 150
                    [parentId] => 
                    [name] => Мясо, птица, деликатесы
                    [sortOrder] => 3
                    [images] => Array
                        (
                            [hash] => 
                            [url] => /upload/iblock/a36/myaso.png
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

мне необходимо перевести его в формат json, но `echo json_encode($arr);` не выводит ничего. Не могу разобраться почему?

Comment: Что значит не выводит ничего? Напишите весь код полностью (массив не в виде print_r) и остальной код, как преобразовываете массив в json и echo

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Скорее всего кодировка данных не та, но в любом случае выведи ошибку джейсон, там будет написано

Comment: Вы правы, json_last_error_msg() - вывел ошибку кодировки.